# EclipseLink JPA Duplicate entry when persisting

Tags: mysql, jpa, eclipselink

I have this strange error when trying to persist an annotated object.

This is my code:

```
if (hashTags != null && !hashTags.isEmpty()) {
    tweet.setHashTags(new LinkedList<HashTag>());
    for (HashTag hashTag : hashTags) {
        HashTag hashTagEntity = em
            .find(HashTag.class, hashTag.getTag());
        if (hashTagEntity == null) {
            LogWrapper.logger.debug("H: " + hashTag.getTag());
            em.persist(hashTag);
            tweet.getHashTags().add(hashTag);
        } else {
            tweet.getHashTags().add(hashTagEntity);
        }
    }
}
```

I know that if you try to persist an existing object you get that exception but I do check that before calling the persist method. Also I can not find the primary key which cause the exception not in my log file nor in my MySQL database and it is confusing me how do I get an exception indicating a primary key value that does not exist in my database in first place.

**Edit**

Those are my annotated classes where I show only the attributes and annotations:

```
@Entity
public class Tweet {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private long id;
    private Usuario usuario;
    private String texto;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date fecha;
    private int numRetweets;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "TWEET_USUARIO_MENCIONADO", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "TWEET_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "USUARIO_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID") })
    private LinkedList<Usuario> usuariosReferenciados;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "TWEET_HASHTAG", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "TWEET_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "HASHTAG_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID") })
    private LinkedList<HashTag> hashTags;
    ...

@Entity
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class Usuario {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private long id;
    private String nombreEnPantalla;
    private int numTweets;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date fechaRegistro;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "usuario", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private LinkedList<Tweet> tweets;
    private int numFollowers;
    private double tweetsPerDay;
    ...

@Entity
public class HashTag {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private String tag;
    ...
```

This is my entire method code where I have the problem:

```
    public Tweet crearTweet(long idTweet, Date fechaTweet, int numRetweets,
            String textoTweet, long idUsuario, Date fechaRegistroUsuario,
            int followersUsuario, String nombreEnPantallaUsuario,
            int numTweetsUsuario, List<Usuario> usuariosMencionados,
            List<HashTag> hashTags) {
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        Tweet tweet = new Tweet();
        tweet.setFecha(fechaTweet);
        tweet.setId(idTweet);
        tweet.setNumRetweets(numRetweets);
        tweet.setTexto(textoTweet);
        em.persist(tweet);
        Usuario user = em.find(Usuario.class, idUsuario);
        if (user == null) {
            user = new Usuario();
            user.setFechaRegistro(fechaRegistroUsuario);
            user.setId(idUsuario);
            user.setNombreEnPantalla(nombreEnPantallaUsuario);
            user.setNumFollowers(followersUsuario);
            user.setNumTweets(numTweetsUsuario);
            em.persist(user);
        }
        tweet.setUsuario(user);
        if (usuariosMencionados != null && !usuariosMencionados.isEmpty()) {
            tweet.setUsuariosReferenciados(new LinkedList<Usuario>());
            for (Usuario usuarioMencionado : usuariosMencionados) {
                Usuario usuarioEntity = em.find(Usuario.class,
                        usuarioMencionado.getId());
                if (usuarioEntity == null) {
                    LogWrapper.logger.debug("U: " + usuarioMencionado.getId()
                            + " " + usuarioMencionado.getNombreEnPantalla());
                    em.persist(usuarioMencionado);
                    tweet.getUsuariosReferenciados().add(usuarioMencionado);
                } else {
                    tweet.getUsuariosReferenciados().add(usuarioEntity);
                }
            }
        }
        if (hashTags != null && !hashTags.isEmpty()) {
            tweet.setHashTags(new LinkedList<HashTag>());
            for (HashTag hashTag : hashTags) {
                HashTag hashTagEntity = em
                        .find(HashTag.class, hashTag.getTag());
                if (hashTagEntity == null) {
                    LogWrapper.logger.debug("H: " + hashTag.getTag());
                    em.persist(hashTag);
                    tweet.getHashTags().add(hashTag);
                } else {
                    tweet.getHashTags().add(hashTagEntity);
                }
            }
        }
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
        return tweet;
    }
```

And this is the entire stack-trace:

```
[EL Warning]: 2015-03-17 01:50:48.411--UnitOfWork(841203)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '??' for key 'PRIMARY'
Error Code: 1062
Call: INSERT INTO HASHTAG (ID) VALUES (?)
    bind => [1 parameter bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(um.es.TFG.modelo.HashTag@7a77e4)
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '??' for key 'PRIMARY'
Error Code: 1062
Call: INSERT INTO HASHTAG (ID) VALUES (?)
    bind => [1 parameter bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(um.es.TFG.modelo.HashTag@7a77e4)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:159)
    at um.es.TFG.dao.jpa.JPATweetDAO.crearTweet(JPATweetDAO.java:76)
    at um.es.TFG.core.TweetProcessorMiner.startProcess(TweetProcessorMiner.java:105)
    at um.es.TFG.main.Main.main(Main.java:24)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '??' for key 'PRIMARY'
Error Code: 1062
Call: INSERT INTO HASHTAG (ID) VALUES (?)
    bind => [1 parameter bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(um.es.TFG.modelo.HashTag@7a77e4)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:902)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:964)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:633)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:560)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2055)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.executeCall(ClientSession.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.insertObject(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:377)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.insertObjectForWrite(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommit(InsertObjectQuery.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommitWithChangeSet(InsertObjectQuery.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.executeWriteWithChangeSet(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:301)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.WriteObjectQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(WriteObjectQuery.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:904)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:803)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWorkObjectLevelModifyQuery(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2896)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1857)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1839)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1790)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitNewObjectsForClassWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitAllObjectsForClassWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitAllObjectsWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.writeAllObjectsWithChangeSet(AbstractSession.java:4260)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabase(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1441)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1531)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.commitRootUnitOfWork(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitAndResume(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1169)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:134)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '??' for key 'PRIMARY'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:360)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:971)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3887)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3823)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2530)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1907)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2141)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2077)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2062)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:892)
    ... 35 more
```

**Edit 2**

If I do em.flush() after every persist operation and comment the following lines in my code, the error stops popping:

```
tweet.getUsuariosReferenciados().add(usuarioMencionado);
tweet.getUsuariosReferenciados().add(usuarioEntity);
tweet.getHashTags().add(hashTag);
tweet.getHashTags().add(hashTagEntity);
```

I am commenting the above lines trying to do as little operations as possible to locate the problem and I already tried without commenting those lines and I still get the error if I do so, but as I said having them commented and flushing after every persist, my code run fine it just does not associate two more lists (HashTags and mentioned users ) of entities with my main entity (Tweet).
So I know now that due to the many persists without flushing I am doing in one transaction I am getting the error but I don't know why it says duplicate key.

Comment: What is the stacktrace of the exception? Can you show how you map the entities?

Comment: Beware that the Usuario <> Tweet relation looks like it is OneToMany on one side and ManyToMany on the other. Question: it appears there is no reverse relation Tweet <> HashTag, right?

Comment: Set EclipseLink logging so that parameters are logged and you might be able to track the reason for the exception: https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging  Search for where the same PK is being inserted and you will find the reason for the problem - it could be a timing issues, as nothing prevents another thread from inserting between the time you have called find and when the transaction commits.  Calling flush immediately would minimize the window that another thread can insert an object with that tag value.

Comment: Chris I have just activated the EclipseLink logging and I will see what it says but i want to know if I should avoid generally to persist and update many entities in one uncommitted transaction, because I think it is the root of all the problem.

Comment: GUIDO, yes there is no reverse relation between Tweet <> HashTag and yet I get errors report there . Also, the Usuario <> Tweet relation looks like it is OneToMany on one side and ManyToMany on the other side because I want them to be two different relations. The OneToMay relation defined in class Usuario is for registering the tweets of a user and it's unidirectional, there is no reverse relation on the Tweet class. The ManyToMany relation in Tweet is for registering a user and the tweet where he does appear mentioned in a middle join table.

Comment: The point of a transactional boundary is that you need all items committed or rolled back as one.  If you are fine with them going in separately and able to handle failures in the latter transactions not being committed, then it is only the resources involved in starting smaller transactions vs larger transactions that would push the decision one way or another.  But I'd track down what is actually causing your issue before deciding on workarounds, as the root  isn't the transaction size, it is a problem in your code and can likely still occur even with smaller transactions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking a deep look at the log produced by EclipseLink, I found that my main problems are due to an incompatible characters encoding. My source was producing text encoded in UTF-8 and my database was using the latin1 encoding. So after inserting a new row with a primary key which can not be represented correctly in latin1 in one of my tables it get inserted as ??? where every interrogation sign replaces a character and the length of the key matches the length of the original word and this is why I was getting the duplicate entry exception, because after inserting for example some strange word composed by 3 strange characters as ??? I will get the duplicate entry exception when trying to insert another different strange word composed by 3 different strange characters. I tried configuring the tables in my database to use UTF-8 but I was still getting the problem because the utf8 in MySQL only uses 3 bytes to represent a character and my source has UTF-8 encoded in 4 bytes. So I used utf8mb4 for my tables and it was not enough to solve the problem and I needed to configure the MySQL server with `character_set_server=utf8mb4`, restart the server and by doing that the Connector/J was able to autodetect the UTF-8 setting properly.